# celery launches more processes than configured

Tags: python, celery

I'm running a celery machine, using redis as the broker with the following configuration:

```
celery -A project.tasks:app worker -l info --concurrency=8
```

When checking the number of celery running processes, I see more than 8.

Is there something that I am missing? Is there a limit for max concurrency?

This problem causes huge memory allocation, and is killing the machine.

Comment: Are you under Posix or Windows system?

Answer (score 1):

With the default settings Celery will always start one more process than the number you ask. This additional process is a kind of bookkeeping process that is used to coordinate the other processes that are part of the worker. It communicates with the rest of Celery, and dispatches the tasks to the processes that actually run the tasks.

Switching to a different pool implementation than the "prefork" default might reduce the number of processes created but that's opening new can of worms.

Answer (score 0):

For the concurrency problem, I have no suggestion.

For the memory problem, you can look at redis configuration in `~/.redis/redis.conf`. You have a `maxmemory` attribute which fix a limit upon tasks…

See the [Redis configuration](http://redis.io/topics/config)

Comment: The redis broker is on a different machine actually, the memory problem is caused by the celery workers themselves